# Do activity trackers count steps when you don't move your arms?

Tags: running, exercise-equipment, walking, tracking

I have a Jawbone up which I wear on my wrist. As far as I know it calculates my step count by measuring the movements of my arm when I walk/run. So if I have my hands inside the hoodie pockets(when it's cold outside) which I think don't involve in any movement when I walk, how does the fitness tracker count steps? Or does it not count at all?

Comment: See also: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/active-minutes-on-flex/23750#23750

Comment: why don't you just try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use various accelerometers and detect motion on numerous algorithms to count at activity.  It won't be 100% accurate but it's not "sorry, you didn't swing your arm buddy... NO REP" either.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out? Go for a walk without swinging your arms and see if it counts a reasonable number of steps.

Technically speaking, the accelerometer will definitely be able to record your steps even if you don't swing your arms.

Answer (score -1):

I used my up today on a treadmill but I was holding on to the arm rest and it did not count my steps. I felt robbed. I wounded if I put it on my ankle that would be better. I'm usually pushing a stroller so my arms are not moving.

Comment: First you should get rid of the UP then.  Second you shouldn't be holding onto a treadmill.

Comment: @DMoore - Why not?

Comment: The general feeling is that if you need to hold on for support, you're going faster than you can control. It also forces a bit of forward posture. Personally, I wind up doing it because I don't pack a heart rate monitor.

Comment: @JohnP - Because while holding onto a treadmill your body is out of position.  I could give you 10 more succinct reasons but basically there is no reason you should ever be holding on unless you have some lower leg injury you are trying to stave off - but at that point not sure you should be on the treadmill.

Comment: @DMoore, Okay? So what about people who are walking on a treadmill while using a standing desk?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck - working on treadmill - which I have done - is not leaning on the treadmill for support.    Also the pace is more activity than exercise.   There is no real issue here other than maybe wrist/neck strain.    Walking for a good pace (for that person) while using the treadmill in even slightest for support produces uneven distribution of effort and can lead to injuries.    The support rails are there for safety not for helping.   This is quite different from a stair stepper or elliptical machines where leaning may provide balance.

Comment: @DMoore, I appreciate the reply. I recently purchased a treadmill for my standing desk. So, naturally I am curious. Anyways, I just bought a cheap pedometer to wear on my waist to help gauge my activity.